# Angular spacing between span and strong tags

Tags: angular

I am having a table which is getting the contents from service and I am using *ngfor to retrieve the data.

One of table row is like this :

```
<tr *ngFor="let d of data.body">
    <td><strong [innerHTML] ="d.header"></strong><br>
    <strong [innerHTML] ="d.subhead"></strong>
</td>
<td>
    <span [innerHTML] ="d.display"></strong><br>
    <span [innerHTML] ="display.subhead"></strong>
</td>
</tr>
```

I am getting the output as

```
Hello  there
Dummy  text
```

And I want the output to be:

```
Hello  there

Dummy  text
```

issue facing: I just need extra spacing between the strong and span tags. I tried to add classes to span and strong tags but its not as expected

Comment: Double your `<br>` tag to create a new line.

Comment: Thanks Ploppy! it does work by adding another br tag,but  let me know if you have any other alternative solution to my issue.Although the br tag adds up a new line  but i need 75% percent of the height of new line. 
ex: 
hello there

dummy text

i want the lower two span's to be little bit closer to strong tags

Comment: You can use css class. Ex: tr.space>td { padding-bottom: 2em; } and then <tr class="space">

Comment: Here is a working exemple with css : https://jsfiddle.net/ygxr5k8s/

Comment: This does not work because I have strong and span elements in my td tag and I need spaces between them

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a CSS question.

You can use `border-spacing` in your table:

```css
table#welcome {
  border-collapse:separate; 
  border-spacing: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<table id="welcome">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <strong>Hello</strong>
      <strong>there</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Dummy</span>
      <span>text</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey Renan, your code snippet is different compared to mine and it doesn't help in solving my issue.

Comment: @user10157709 Angular will render (at the end) the html like I answered. You just need to set the CSS as I did, this is not a Angular issue, it's a CSS issue.